# Rails 4 get count for has_many through, multiple levels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

A `army` has `platoons`. Each `platoon` has `squadrons`. Each `squadron` has `soldiers`.

Given an `army` id, how can I get a count of how many soldiers are in it? This is for Rails 4, there are older answers for Rails 3 that don't seem to use the latest Active Record methods.

```
@army = Army.find(:id)

@army.platoons # This will return all platoons.

@armay.platoons.squadrons # Error: undefined method 'squadrons' for #<Platoon::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007ff6f7752380>
```

Comment: Did you mean an `army` as many `platoons` instead of `squadrons`? Please review the names in your question, they look like total mess.

Comment: Fixed the one misnaming. Thanks for pointing it out Tamer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your army model you need:

```
has_many :platoons
has_many :squadrons, through: :platoons
has_many :soldiers, through: :squadrons
```

Now you can use.

```
@army.soldiers.count
```